# Highcharts - can't find the export server files

Tags: maven, highcharts

Trying to install the export module but none of these links below (which is trying to be fetched) work:

Downloading: http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/com/highcharts/export/highcharts-export-convert/2.1.0/highcharts-export-convert-2.1.0.pom

Downloading: http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/com/highcharts/export/highcharts-export-convert/2.1.0/highcharts-export-convert-2.1.0.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/highcharts/export/highcharts-export-convert/2.1.0/highcharts-export-convert-2.1.0.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.highcharts.export:highcharts-export-convert:jar:2.1.0 is missing, no dependency information available

Downloading: http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/com/highcharts/export/highcharts-export-convert/2.1.0/highcharts-export-convert-2.1.0.jar

Downloading: http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/com/highcharts/export/highcharts-export-convert/2.1.0/highcharts-export-convert-2.1.0.jar

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/highcharts/export/highcharts-export-convert/2.1.0/highcharts-export-convert-2.1.0.jar

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: Where have the files gone?

Comment: To install export server use instruction from Docs:
http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server

File for download are provided on github:
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-export-server

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly your problem is, but this works for me:
Highcharts project java sources can be obtained from [github](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-export-server/tree/master/java/highcharts-export) (as specified in the ["Setting up the export server" manual](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server)).
After that, using a basic maven configuration (via settings.xml) with just the official maven repository specified as the single repostitory
`<mirror>
    <id>mavenCentral</id>
    <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    <url>http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=</url>
</mirror>`

all dependecies get downloaded and the project gets build (`mvn clean install`).